V 2 passport from South Africa , what does this mean?
I work in UAE,when I travelled for the first time from OR Tambo airport (Johannesburg) the immigration was a bit confused and asked what If you married to a foreigner,I said no I am not. He stamped my passport I went through.
When I travelled back last year from DXB (Dubai) to the same airport, the airline I was using called SA embassy to double check my passport and I managed to take my flight back.
Now my concern everytime is that am being interviewed all the times only to found out there’s a name of a stranger on the system underneath my original names. How do I fix that? My passport will expire in 2027 I can’t change it as my residence ID will cost me if I have to change it.Can the department of Home Affairs be able to correct that?

What did the department of Home Affairs say when you asked them?

Changing ID will no change anything (but the document). It is just possible that an other person have your name so you may be flagged, and further question to check that. Or check the ticket. Maybe airline put you as female/male, but different from passport

What does the V in the title mean?
